# Permissions for /Volumes are different with Network vs Local Time Machine folders?

Tags: network, time-machine, unix, smb

I've been running local Time Machine backups to an external FireWire drive since I got my MacBook a few months ago. But now that my wife picked up a MacBook as well, I'd like to move to a solution that works without USB/FireWire.

I run two servers at home, an unRAID server as my file storage server, and an Ubuntu 12.04 server as my front end (mostly for things like Sabnzbd, SickBeard, ect...). I found this post the other day and followed it to the letter:

http://blog.bertelsen.co/2012/07/time-machine-server-on-ubuntu-1204.html

The difference for me though, was I mounted my unRAID "TimeMachine" share as a local drive on Ubuntu (/mnt/TimeMachine) by modifying my fstab file. So far, so good.

I'm able to select the new networked TimeMachine drive on our Mac's and choose it as the hard drive. But when I try to run a backup, I get the following error:

"Time Machine couldn't complete the back to "homeserver".
The Backup disk image "/Volumes/Time Machine on Ubuntu/Kris' MacBook Pro.sparesbundle" could not be created (error 22)."

I did a bit of searching and found that permissions seem off in my /Volumes directory on the mac. For example, I have a "/Volumes/Time Capsule" drive mounted which is my external drive connected via FireWire. It has kris:staff as the owners, and 775 as the permissions.

However, the "/Volumes/TM on Ubuntu" that I gets mounted when I try to use the network share for Time Machine backups has root:wheel as the owners, and 700 as the permissions.

Why is that? Do I need to configure something differently on my Ubuntu Server to get the mac to mount this with proper permissions?

Comment: I'm trying to weed through the steps - is this basically a matter of one mac gets error 22 and the other does not? (or do both macs now get error 22)?

Comment: @bmike - Sorry, both users are unable to work properly and both are getting error 22.